# R - Create a new data frame with removing all the "NAN" element

Tags: r, dataframe, nan

Mymatrix is a data frame and remove several columns from this frame. Then I also want to remove all the NAN element from the new data frame. But the code below does not show a correct answer.

```
OKHS <- Mymatrix[,c(-6,-7,-12,-13,-14),na.rm=TRUE]
```

Comment: A [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested code:

```
OKHS <- na.omit(Mymatrix[,c(-6,-7,-12,-13,-14)])
```